# I am playing small audio clip (10-15 second) in infinite loop but there is 100-200 millisecond unnecessary pause between loop

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am playing small audio clip using `MediaPlayer` in infinite loop but there is 100-200 millisecond unnecessary pause between n the current loop ending and the next one beginning.

Which take very small pause between sound but annoying to user so is there any solution.

```
     MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
try {

    AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = getAssets().openFd(file);
    mp.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(), descriptor.getStartOffset(), descriptor.getLength());
    descriptor.close();

    mp.prepare();
    mp.setLooping(true);
    mp.start();
   } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: maybe the audio clip itself has a silent period within itself?

Comment: No I have checked audio clip is ready itself.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue by using SoundPool instead of MediaPlayer,

```
    SoundPool soundPool;
int soundID;
boolean plays = false, loaded = false;
float actVolume, maxVolume, volume;
AudioManager audioManager;       




    audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
    actVolume = (float) audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    maxVolume = (float) audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    volume = actVolume / maxVolume;

    this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    soundPool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId, int status) {

        }
    });
    soundID = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.audiofile, 1);


    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            soundPool.play(soundID, volume, volume, 1, -1, 1f);
        }
    },1000);
```